# How to pull docker image from Harbor in go lang code

Tags: docker, go

I want to download the docker image from the Harbor registry.
Just like in the below url the image is being downloaded from the AWS ECR registry.

https://aemdemir.com/posts/how-to-pull-docker-images-from-amazon-ecr-private-registry-in-go/

I am bit confused how will i implement the Authconfig for the harbor.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem. This is the first time I am answering to my question.

So to pull a private docker image from the harbor registry from golang we will be using the following libraries.

```
import (
"context"
"encoding/base64"
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"io"
"os"

"github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
"github.com/docker/docker/api/types/registry"
"github.com/docker/docker/client"
"github.com/rs/zerolog/log")

func ImagePullHarbor(img string) error {
  ctx := context.Background()

  authConfig := registry.AuthConfig{
    Username:      "harbor_registry_username",
    Password:      "harbor_registry_password",
    ServerAddress: "harbor_registry_url",
  }

  encodedJSON, err := json.Marshal(authConfig)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  authStr := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(encodedJSON)
  
  # docker client is use to pull the image.
  dockerCli, err := newDockerClient()
  if err != nil {
    log.Error().Msgf("failed to create docker client: %w", err)
    return err
  }

  out, err := dockerCli.ImagePull(ctx, img, types.ImagePullOptions{RegistryAuth: authStr})
  if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to pull image: %w", err)
  }
  defer out.Close()

  _, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, out)
  if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to read image logs: %w", err)
  }
  return err
}

func newDockerClient() (*client.Client, error) {
  cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create docker client 1: %w", err)
  }
  return cli, nil
}
```

After running the above function from golang. Run

> docker images

You can see the pulled images.

Bonus: You may have to run **sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock**.